# How to render Java FX application without using graphic card?

Tags: netbeans, javafx

I have developed a Java FX application in my laptop which has 512mb NVIDIA grapic card using netbeans IDE 7.3.1 + JDK 7. So all the transitions coded was rendering so smooth.

Once when i tried to execute the same project in my office desktop(win7 + 64 bit + with no graphic card + netbeans IDE 8 + JDK7 ) the transitions coded had poor rendering .It was very slow which made me feel down and unable to impement the project

**PROBLEM:**
Will it work properly once if convert it to a single runnable jar? (or) is there any option to convert it to a web application?
Please let me know if any other solution is present to make it work smoothly in desktop ? 
solutions are really welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every computer running windows have a Graphic Card. It might not be a good one, but it is still there. (The newest intel processors [i3,i5,i7] "have" a graphics card), so while you may not have an specific and distinct hardware for it, it is still there.

If you convert to a single runnable Jar, the problem will still be the same, as you will be still running on the computer. And even the self-contained as it just includes a full JRE bundled with your program.

If you look at the [Deployment Overview](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/deploy_overview.htm) you will see the different features of each deployment style:

[image: features of deployment]

As you can see your better chances are at the *right side* as it will run from a server and the computer will get just the webpage.

Comment: @kyllopardium Hi kyollopardium, Thanks a lot for your information, IS there any blog explaining steps to convert the project to web based remote kind as you mentined above?